# Wikitude with Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, augmented-reality, wikitude

I'm making a POI AR application as a part of my university project. I have downloaded the JavaScript version of the Wikitude on my machine. I also followed all the steps to implement Wikitude library into my project (update the Manifest, the gradle) as described here:

http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/android/setupguideandroid.html#setup-guide-android

But as I never used JavaScript I have no idea where the code goes in Android Studio. So i cannot even follow the POI example that is given in the documentation:

http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/android/poi.html#point-of-interest-poi

I know it's a stupid question, but I cannot find a tutorial or at least a hint anywhere.

Just in case my Android Studio version is 2.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [guide](https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/5.1/android/samples.html) clearly explains the usage of wikitude's JS SDK in native Android.

Comment: That's true, it even has links to how to implement it in Android Studio. I feel silly. Thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: Mark the answer as complete if it did help !